# Cannot move windows side-by-side join after updating 20.04

Tags: desktop-environments, window, window-placement

After updating to Ubuntu 20.04 I'm not able anymore to set 2 windows side by side (left and right) and change their percent of the screen while moving the join (in the middle)

This was possible in previous version like Ubuntu 19.10. Maybe they changed the way of doing it. Let me explain myself with graphics:
[Move windows stuck together in Ubuntu 19.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bwyy.png)

Steps to reproduce it:

1. Update to Ubuntu 20.04
2. Pair side-by-side windows, ex: FireFox (left) and Visual Studio Code (right) or OBS (left) and Chromium (right)...
3. Now that the 2 windows occupy 50% of the available area try to move the middle.

Note: If one of the windows is the internal Ubuntu File Browser you can do it but when you are using external apps (no those ones from the system) you cannot.

Comment: Still works from me on Ubuntu 20.04, also an upgrade from 19.10

Comment: So, what I'm doing wrong? I don't have the cursor when I have for example Visual Studio Code (left side) and Chrome (right side)? Do I have to press a key?

Comment: It was **Pixel Saver** extension, I turned it off and now it works : ) thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with *Pixel Saver* extension.

After turning it off everything works as expected : )